# Understanding why we need "mod n" in the definition of $r(j)$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, permutations, group-actions, dihedral-groups

I was trying to understand the action of $D_{2n}$ on $A$ given here [$D_{2n}$ Acting on the set consisting of Opposite Pairs of Vertices of a regular n-gon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950719/d-2n-acting-on-the-set-consisting-of-opposite-pairs-of-vertices-of-a-regular) , specifically I was trying to understand this part of the solution:

` If we define $r(j) = j − 1\mod n$ with $0 ≤ j ≤ n − 1$, then we get $r(i) = i − 1,$ if $i ≥ 1 $and $r(0) = n − 1$.Then to any pair $(i, i + n/2)$ with $0 < i < n/2, r(i) = i − 1, r(i + n/2) =i − 1 + n/2, $i.e. $r(i, i + n/2) = (i − 1, i − 1 + n/2) = a_{i−1} \in A$

Thus we can conclude that $r(a_i) = a_{i−1} \mod \frac{n}{2}$

And we define the reflection is about the line connecting vertices $0, 3,$
thus $s(j) = −j \mod n,$ thus to any $a_i, s(i) = −i \mod n = n − i, s(i + n/2) = n/2 − i,$thus $s(a_i) = (n/2 − i, n − i) = a−i \mod n/2$. Thus we have proved s · $a \in A$, $r · a \in A$ for any $a \in A$, therefore $g · a \in A$, for any $g \in D_{2n}, a \in A.$`

But I have the following questions about this part of the solution:

1- why we need "mod n" in the definition of $r(j)$ and $s(j)$? what confuses me is that $0 ≤ j ≤ n − 1$ so I guess the value of $r(j)$ will never exceeds $n$ and similarlyy $s(j)$ I guess.

2- why $r(0) = n-1$ and not $n$?

3- why the value of $r(j)$ implies the given value of $r(i)$?

4- why $i \geq 1$ in a part and $0 < i < n/2$ in another part? are they different $i$? and shouldn 't it be $0 \leq i < n/2$ instead?

5- Why $r(i + n/2) =i − 1 + n/2$ and why $s(i + n/2) = n/2 − i$?

Could anyone help me understand the answers to those problems please?

Comment: Why do you think $r(0)=n$? The definition clearly says $r(0)=0-1 \mod n$ and $-1=n-1 \mod n$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @ancientmathematician so you are saying that there is a typo in the answer, am I correct? personally, I feel like this answer has many typos in it and this is what confuses me.

Comment: @Shaun do you mean I should ask five questions related to this one answer? I just feel that sometimes they are just typos in the answer and if I get a comment as an answer (because the answers maybe pretty much short) that will lead me to write the question 5 times and delete it 5 times. anyway, I will be more cautious while writing my questions next time and I will try to ask only one or 2 questions in my question, it is just in this case I am guessing that the answers are in a similar trend.

Comment: No.  I am trying to get you to explain why you think there's anything difficult about applying the definition and getting the stated results.

Comment: @ancientmathematician for me, $r(0)$ should be equal to $n-1 \mod n$ as you said, I agree. But I do not agree with that $r(0) = n.$

Comment: Alas, you are the one who asks in 2 why $r(0)$ is not $n$.

Comment: A definition is given for $r$, namely $r(j)=j-1\mod n$. Most of your queries seem to be of the form "why is $r(x)=x-1\mod n$?" I can't understand what the difficulty is.

Comment: Oh, my bad, yes. I think what confuses me in the OP answer is that he did not write "mod n". @ancientmathematician

Comment: Yeah, regarding your last comment, what confuses me in that definition the "mod n" that is written in it.

Comment: You need the $\mod n$ so that $0$ has someplace to map to, you want the $0$-th vertex and $n$-th vertex to be the same.